# Trouble understanding a paragraph within a French contract

Tags: france, homeownership, loan

I cannot understand the last paragraph of an article in a reservation contract to acquire our main residence.

The context: We advance 1% of the sum to "book" the Appartement we wish to buy while we try to find a loan.

Anyhow, the contract is in french.

Here's the complete article (Article 6):

> Le Réservataire déclare dans les conditions particulières le mode de financement du prix de son acquisition.
>
> Dans l'hypothèse où le Réservataire ferait appel à des prêts
> bancaires, conformément aux disposition des articles L312-1 et suivant
> le code de la construction relative à l'information et à la protection
> de l'emprunteur dans le domaine immobilier. les présentes seront
> soumises à la condition suspensive de l'obtention par le Réservataire,
> au plus tard dans le délai stipulé aux conditions particulières, d'une
> offre de prêt dont les caractéristiques principales sont énoncées
> auxdites conditions particulières.
>
> Le Réservataire s'oblige à déposer auprès du ou des organismes
> prêteurs une demande de prêt avec pièces nécessaires à la date
> figurant eu paragraphe B des conditions particulière du présent
> contrat, soit dans les trente (30) jours de la présente signature. Le
> réservataire s'oblige également à poursuivre les démarches nécessaires
> à la bonne fin de cette demande, et à en justifier au réservant à sa
> première demande.
>
> Cette justification sera apportée, soit par une copie du récépissé qui
> lui sera délivré par la banque, soit par l'accusé de réception en cas
> d'envoi par lettre recommandée.
>
> Le Réservataire s'oblige à notifier au Réservent la décision (des ou)
> de l'organisme prêteur par lettre recommandée adressée eu plus tard
> dans un délai de huit (8) jours de ladite décision.
>
> Si un refus de prêt lui est notifié, le Réservataire s'engage à
> déposer une nouvel et même demande de prêt, dans les 8 jours suivant
> cette notification auprès de l'interlocuteur du RESERVANT chez le
> courtier «Meilleurtaux.com » et de répandre avec diligence à toutes
> les demandes d'informations ou de fourniture de documents qui lui
> serait faite ce qu'accepte expressément le RESERVATAIRE.
>
> En cas de refus de prêt, la notification devra, pour entrainer la mise
> en jeu de la condition suspensive, être accompagnée de(s) la
> demande(s) de prêt dans les conditions ci-dessous et du(es) refus
> justifié(s) de(s) l'organisme préteur(s).
>
> A défaut de production par le Réservataire des justificatifs
> ci-dessous, les présentes seront, en conséquence et si bon semble au
> Réservant, caduques et le dépôt de garantie demeurera acquis au
> Réservant.
>
> Le Réservataire déclare qu'il n'envisage pas de solliciter d'autres
> prêts que celui ou ceux indiqués pour financer son acquisition.

And this last part I cannot understand :

> Il reconnait avoir été informé qu'en conséquence il ne saurait se
> préveloir du bénéfice des dispositions de l'article L312-1 et suivant
> du code de la consommation, en cas de non obtention d'un crédit autre
> que celui ou ceux qu'il aura mentionnés, notamment pour obtenir la
> restitution du dépôt de garantie stipulé ci-après.

If there is information missing, I'd be happy to provide it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot understand the last paragraph of an article in a reservation contract to acquire our main residence.

My understanding of the clause is that you knowingly waive your rights to reimbursement pursuant to L312-1 (note the initial reference reads "*construction*" but the latter reads "*consommation*") if your denied [loan] application is for a loan other than the one(s) you notified to the seller.

The clause requires you to keep the seller up-to-date regarding the application(s) for loan with which you intend to purchase the house. Thus, a failure to keep the client duly updated is penalized by precluding reimbursement. One possible (?) justification for that clause is the seller's need for assurance that he will not incur a loss in the event that you default.

I had some trouble construing "*il ne saurait se préveloir du bénéfice*" (in part because maybe the contract reads "prévaloir"). Unless you feel confident about the meaning of that phrase, it is in your best interest to ask the seller to reword the clause in terms that are clear enough to you.

Comment: But how would he incur a loss if I come up with another loaner that I had not declared before?

Comment: That was only my conjecture (hence the question mark in parentheses), in reference to a risk of buyer's default, and without knowing other terms of the contract. Perhaps legislation requires a seller of real estate to have that information up-to-date for purposes of liens or recovery from lender. If you have not signed the contract, you might want to ask the seller to clarify in the contract the intent behind that clause. Also, please note I added a paragraph to the answer.